# Remove duplicate records from view result with pager

Tags: 7, views, search

My project is setup in Drupal 7 and i am using search API for display my custom search result. Actually i want to show search result based on two content types content so i have configure the search api for those content type and select the fields which i want for search and then indexing the content.

For display the search result i am using drupal View of Index node type.
But the problem is that in my search result i am getting duplicate result because of some contents have same titles but having different body text.

I want to remove search result which have duplicate title. (Custom field created by myself)

I have tried some custom solution by View hook but its not working properly its give pager issue

```
function custom_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'search_books') {
   $view_ISBN = array();
    foreach ($view->result AS $key => $res_view) {
        $ISBN = $res_view->entity->field_isbn[und][0]['value'];
       if (!in_array($ISBN,$view_ISBN)) {
                    $view_ISBN[] = $ISBN;
             unset($view->result[$key]);
            }
    }

    $view->query->pager->total_items = count($view->result);
    $view->query->pager->update_page_info();

 } 
}
```

This remove the duplicate result but it gives wrong pager result.

I have also tried the Query alter hook but its not working for me.

```
function custom_query_alter($query) {

  if (isset($query->alterMetaData)) {
    if (isset($query->alterMetaData['view'])) {
      if($query->alterMetaData['view']->name == 'search_books') {
        $fields =& $query->getGroupBy();
        // Tried various fields to check which was the field creating the problem.

        $query->groupBy('field_isbn');
        $query->distinct = TRUE;

      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have also tried to install "views_distinct" module and distinct the field from view but its also gives me pager issue.

Any Idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: From the description these are not really duplicates, but different records with the same title, is that correct? If so, I can see why what you have tried won't work. Search API queries can't be altered as if they were SQL, either. What's the value in having the duplicates in your data? Could you unpublish them or flag them in some other way so you can remove them from the query?

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong Yes, They are different records with same title. title and some other field is same for some records so i want to display only single entry in search result and on click of title i want to display all content list which have same titles because those field are referenced by taxonomy.

Sorry, I can't remove or unpublished those contents.

Comment: Recording to your comment above the `field_isbn` field is term reference ?

Comment: @berramou Yes this is term reference

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "wrong pager result"? Wrong total count, missing items, pages without items? Is it possible to have an item without a duplicate? If so, maybe your problem is that `custom_views_pre_render(&$view)` also removes any item without a duplicate. Unless I am misunderstanding what is going on, you should change your `if` block to something like `if (!in_array($ISBN,$view_ISBN)) { $view_ISBN[] = $ISBN; } else{ unset($view->result[$key]); }` This would remove all duplicates. FYI, `$view->result` contains just the items for the current page, not all the results from the query.